# Split text based on list of keywords

Tags: python, list, dictionary, split

I am working on a project with to convert raw text received from Google speech to text API to structured data which looks something like this:

**"Heading COVID-19 Test 2. Hypothesis. The vaccine still works. Observations. Point. Pfizer is 98% effective. Point. Moderna is 97% effective."**

Which gives result similar to this:

## Covid-19 Test 2

#### Hypothesis

The vaccine still works.

#### Observations:

- Pfizer is 98% effective
- Moderna is 97% effective

I have hard coded functions to find keywords such as Heading, Hypothesis, Observations and then apply specific functions as per the name.

```
result.alternatives[0].transcript = 'Heading.Covid Test 2.Hypothesis.Vaccine still works.'

keyword_list = ['heading', 'hypothesis'] 
Text_List = result.alternatives[0].transcript.split('.')
Text_List = [x.lower() for x in Text_List]
```

Text_List looks something like this `['heading', 'covid test 2', 'hypothesis', 'vaccine still works']`

Then I pair the Keywords with the next text and add them in a dictionary.

```
dictionary = {}
for k in keyword_list:
    if(k in Text_List):
        dictionary[k] = Text_List[Text_List.index(k) + 1]
```

The dictionary looks something like this = `{'heading': 'covid test 2', 'hypothesis': 'vaccine still works'}`

Which are then sent to a function which adds the mark-up as per the Key values.

This works for Keywords which take the next line as input.
The problem arises while working with *Observations*.

**Observations. Point. Pfizer is 98% effective. Point. Moderna is 97% effective.**

If we Split the above text with `Split('.')`.
we get something like `['observations', 'point', 'pfizer is 98% effective', 'point', 'moderna is 97% effective']`

Which when given in out function above to make a dictionary gives us `{'heading': 'covid test 2', 'hypothesis': 'vaccine still works', 'observations': 'point'}` because we are splitting it on period (.)

So I was wondering if there is a method to split the texts on the base of keywords in our list?
For eg.

**"Heading COVID-19 Test 2. Hypothesis. The vaccine still works. Observations. Point. Pfizer is 98% effective. Point. Moderna is 97% effective. Save"**

And it splits the above text on `keyword_list = ['heading', 'hypothesis', 'observations', 'save']`

giving us something like `{'heading': 'covid test 2', 'hypothesis': 'vaccine still works', 'observations': 'Point. Pfizer is 98% effective. Point. Moderna is 97% effective.',  'save': ''}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
keyword_list = ['heading', 'hypothesis', 'observations', 'save']
input_text = "Heading COVID-19 Test 2. Hypothesis. The vaccine still works. Observations. Point. Pfizer is 98 effective. Point. Moderna is 97 effective. Save"
lc_input = input_text.lower()
indices = [lc_input.find(word) for word in keyword_list]
for i in range(len(indices)):
    try:
        # append to a list or a dict
        print (lc_input[indices[i]:indices[i+1]])
    except:
        # this applies to the last iteration
        print (lc_input[indices[i]:len(lc_input)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this is my first time here answering but here's my take. You can try to parse them with the find function which returns the index of the phrase, adjust it for the word length and then partition them based on the indexes of the key words that appears in your string. This of course only work very well when all of your phrases have the same order for keywords as you specify but if you want to split by keywords I think this is not a bad approach.

```
test = 'Heading.Covid Test 2.Hypothesis.Vaccine still works.Observations. Point. Pfizer is 98% effective. Point. Moderna is 97% effective.'
keys = ['Heading','Hypothesis','Observations']

indx = []

for i in range(len(keys)):
    if test.find(keys[i])!= -1:
        indx.append(int(test.find(keys[i])))
    else:
        #you may have to do some processing here if keys is not found
        print('Key not found')

dic = {}
for i in range(len(keys)):
    if i != len(keys)-1:
        dic[keys[i]] = test[(indx[i]+len(keys[i])):indx[i+1]]
    elif i == len(keys)-1:
        dic[keys[i]] = test[indx[i]+len(keys[i]):]

print(dic)
```